# Is there a way to prevent Excel from automatically setting Application.ScreenUpdating to True

Tags: excel, api, events, vba, com

I have a COM (C++) API that listens for data updates from a server and writes these updates to a sheet. These updates are handled in VBA code and can arrive multiple times a second. In order to write these updates to the sheet in the most efficient manner, I use the following premise:

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 <UPDATE CODE>
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

In fact, I schedule a procedure to do this regular intervals where `ScreenUpdating = False` for about 20 seconds, then it is set to true so the data can update and then I set it to false again. i have found that this is a better option than setting ScreenUpdates + Calculation explicitly simply because of the highfrequency of the updates I receive.

The Problem:

I have read [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) that excel sets `ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of each method that disables it which is not what I need.

The Question:

Is there some way to force Excel to not automatically enable `ScreenUpdating`?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. But the only idea I have is looking into APIs. It would interesting to see if there is a solution to this besides just putting the .ScreenUpdating=False in the highest hierarchy of your code.

Comment: I've tried a few different approaches: putting all the code in one module, calling .ScreenUpdaing=False in EVERY (yes every) method but none of this seems to work. I'll post back if I find a solution. Any idea on API's I might use?

Comment: In my experience (and understanding), Excel _does not_ automatically reset screen updating, calculation, display alerts, or anything else that your code has set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if these help with your APIs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee461765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I just searched google for "list of apis microsoft"